# How to insert Node at end of Linked List?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am a beginner in Data Structures and I want to know how insert node at the **end** of a linked list.
With the following code I am able to insert node in the beginning and in the any other position except at the end of the linked list. But when it comes to inserting a node at the end I am unable to do so.

```
void Insert(NODE *head,int n,int pos)
{
     NODE  *temp, *newnode;
     int i;
     for(temp = head, i = 1; ( temp != NULL ) && ( i <= pos-1 ); i++)
     {

         if(temp->next==NULL)
         {
             printf("\nPosition is out of range.\n\n");
         }
         

     }
          newnode = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
          newnode->info = n;
          newnode->next = temp->next;
          temp->next = newnode;
}
```

When I go for inserting node at the end it gives following output
" Position out of range."
I sort of understand why it gives that output, but I am not able to find how should I change my code.
Thank You.

Comment: I cannot believe not even *one* of the many questions and answers returned from searching for [`[c] How to insert Node at end of Linked List`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+How+to+insert+Node+at+end+of+Linked+List) were of any value here.

Comment: "I am able to insert node in the beginning and at the end of the linked list. But when it comes to inserting a node at the end I am unable to do so."  These two sentences contradict each other.

Comment: I am sorry for the mistake in the question, necessary edits have been made.

Comment: William Pursell , I have made necessary changes.

Answer (score 0):

Comment on your code :

```
for(temp = head, i = 1; ( temp != NULL ) && ( i <= pos-1 ); i++)
{

     if(temp->next==NULL) // Adding at the end means that you add when
                          // temp-> next is NULL
     {
         printf("\nPosition is out of range.\n\n");
     }
     

 }
```

For example, if you a 1 element in the list and insert at position 2, you will have (i <= pos-1) true and (temp->next==NULL) true.